# How can I force update my UI immediately in Swift 5 using UIKit?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit

I ran into a problem with my UI, which is not updating immediately.

I am calling `someCustomView.isHidden = false` first. After that I create a new instance of a new `View Controller`. Inside the new VCs `viewDidLoad()`, I am loading a "new Machine Learning Model", which takes some time.

```swift
private func someFuncThatGetsCalled() {

    print("1")

    self.viewLoading.isHidden = false

    print("2")

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToModelVCSegue", sender: nil)

}
```

As soon as I press the button that calls this function, "1" and "2" is printed in the console. However the view is not getting visible before the `viewDidLoad()` of my new VC is finished.

Is there any possibility to force update a `UIView` immediately? `setNeedsDisplay()` did not work for me.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple problems...

If you have a view controller that *"takes some time"* to load, you should not try to do it in that manner.

The app will be non-responsive and appear "frozen."

A much better approach would be:

- on `someFuncThatGetsCalled()`

  - hide `viewLoading` and replace it with an activity indicator (spinner, or something else that let's the user know the app is not stuck)
  - instantiate your `ModelVC`
  - when `ModelVC` has finished its setup, have it inform the current VC (via delegate)
  - current VC *then* shows / navigates to the already instantiated and prepared `ModelVC`

Or, probably a better option... Move your time-consuming setup in `ModelVC` to a point *after* the view has appeared. You can show an activity indicator in `viewDidLoad()`. That is really the most common UX - you see it all the time when the new VC has to retrieve remote data to display - and it would fit wit what users have come to expect.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is another good idea to solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Use `layoutIfNeeded()` [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622507-layoutifneeded)

> **layoutIfNeeded()**
>
> Lays out the subviews immediately, if layout updates are pending.
>   Use this method to force the view to update its layout immediately. When using Auto Layout, the layout engine updates the position of views as needed to satisfy changes in constraints. Using the view that receives the message as the root view, this method lays out the view subtree starting at the root. If no layout updates are pending, this method exits without modifying the layout or calling any layout-related callbacks.

So As a rule of thumb,

`layoutifneeded` : Immediate (current update cycle) , synchronous call

`setNeedsLayout` :relaxed ( wait till Next Update cycle) , asynchronous call

So, `layoutIfNeeded` says update immediately please, whereas `setNeedsLayout` says please update but you can wait until the next update cycle.

how to use

```
yourView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

You can also refer to the diagram to better remember the order of these passes

[image]

Source [Apple docs on layoutIfNeeded](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622507-layoutifneeded)

Image credit [Medium artcle](https://medium.com/@varunrathi28/ios-setneedslayout-vs-layoutifneeded-ceb1c8335abe)